# why use not operation in regex function salesforce

Tags: regex, salesforce

Could any of you pls explain the following code.  Why NOT is used for?

```
NOT(REGEX(Zip_Postal_Code__c, "[0-9]{5}"))
```

Comment: It looks like a boolean expression... should return true if the `ZIP` does NOT have five digits.

Comment: It is usually used to negate the result of some operation.

Comment: Thanks  Washington Guedes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code is in a Validation rule. Validation rules will show an error if the result of evaluating the code is TRUE.

`REGEX(Zip_Postal_Code__c, "[0-9]{5}")` will evaluate to TRUE if the Zip code in that field is valid and to FALSE if the value is not valid which would cause the validation to throw an error if the Zip is valid. Since the intention is probably to throw an error when the Zip code is NOT valid, the NOT() function is used to invert or negate the result of the REGEX() function.